# How to pass pod_name in pod_down grafana alert message

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

I created the pod_down alert rule and this is my query:

```
sum by(namespace,pod) (changes(kube_pod_status_ready{condition="true"}[5m]))
```

[1. alert rule query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0fUY.png)

[2. alert rule classic conditiion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmJ5G.png)

[3. alert rule message template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH6Ak.png)

I want to pass pod_name into the alert message template.

> **pod**= nginx-3yh536hs-kd pod was down
>
> **environment** = dev
>
> **namespace** = default
>
> **summary** = pod_down alert rule.

---

@markalex So, I found the simple template and tried it for the discord alert message (Contact points)
but still, I can't get the correct output

template

```
{{ define "default_template" }}
  **[{{ index .Annotations "summary" }}]**
  **Environment:** {{ index .Labels "environment" }}
  **Pod:** {{ index .Labels "pod" }}
  **Type:** {{ index .Labels "type" }}
  
  **Error Message:**
  {{ .Annotations.summary }}
{{ end }}
```

discord alert message

```
**[
[RESOLVED] Pod Down Alert Development (postgresql-backup dev postgresql-backup k8s)

Grafana v10.1.5
Spidey Bot
BOT
 — Today at 10:07 AM
**[
[FIRING:1]  (TestAlert Grafana)

Grafana v10.1.5
```

Comment: What your template supposed to do? Specifically it's not clear part about `B[0-9]+`. How [default template] doesn't satisfy your needs?

Comment: @markalex I want to pass only label values, not the passed source, and silence links in the alert message. so I need a simple template for the discord alert message. and I also mentioned that I already used the template and my discord alert message output in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got my correct alert message template.

**Pod CPU high alert**

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{container!="pod",namespace="default",container!=""}[5m])) by (pod) * 1024
```

[alert condition image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ37r.png)

**Add Summary into anntations**

```
The host **{{ index $labels "pod" }}** has exceeded 500Mi CPU usage for the last 5 minutes
```

*and **save rule and exit***

**create default message template.**

```
{{ define "slack.title_NEW_1702356284919" }}
{{ len .Alerts.Firing }} firing alert(s), {{ len .Alerts.Resolved }} resolved alert(s)
{{ end }}

{{ define "slack.print_alert" -}}
[{{.Status}}] {{ .Labels.alertname }}
Labels:
{{ range .Labels.SortedPairs -}}
- {{ .Name }}: {{ .Value }}
{{ end -}}
{{ if .Annotations -}}
Annotations:
{{ range .Annotations.SortedPairs -}}
- {{ .Name }}: {{ .Value }}
{{ end -}}
{{ end -}}
{{- end }}

{{ define "slack.message" -}}
{{ if .Alerts.Firing -}}
{{ len .Alerts.Firing }} firing alert(s):
{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}
{{ template "slack.print_alert" . }}
{{ end -}}
{{ end }}
{{ if .Alerts.Resolved -}}
{{ len .Alerts.Resolved }} resolved alert(s):
{{ range .Alerts.Resolved }}
{{ template "slack.print_alert" .}}
{{ end -}}
{{ end }}
{{- end }}
```

**output**
[discord alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXAOD.png)